# How to use SequenceModifier in AndEngine

Tags: andengine

I am using AndEngine for animation.I want to use Modifier in sequential mode.

```java
final float centerX = (BallShakeActivity.CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
        final float centerY = (BallShakeActivity.CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;
         ball = new AnimatedSprite(centerX, centerY, this.mFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        ball.animate(50);
        scene.attachChild(ball);

    MoveModifier modifier =  new MoveModifier(10,CAMERA_WIDTH ,CAMERA_HEIGHT/2, 0,CAMERA_HEIGHT );
    ball.registerEntityModifier(modifier);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Queue multiple entity modifiers in AndEngine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170486/queue-multiple-entity-modifiers-in-andengine)

Comment: First answer in google gives you this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170486/queue-multiple-entity-modifiers-in-andengine